# Is there another way to add an onclick function on an input button?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried onclick function on the `intSubmit` but for some reason when the code is executed the onclick is called once and when you press the button it does nothing. I tried using "debug()" but that, as I figured, doesn't work at all.

```
if(qType === "INTEGER"){
        let intAnswer = document.createElement("input");
        intAnswer.type = "text";
        intAnswer.id = "intA";
        let intSubmit = document.createElement("input");
        intSubmit.type = "button";
        intSubmit.onclick = debug();
        intSubmit.value = "Submit";
        qDiv.appendChild(intAnswer);
        qDiv.appendChild(intSubmit);
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `()` after `debug`. You're calling the function when you assign it, not when the click happens.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much. I didn't even think of that.

Comment: why you need ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the method by using the `()`. Just pass the method as a parameter without calling it

```
intSubmit.onclick = debug;
```

Answer (score 0):

**you function is not bind properly, the way you binding function is wrong.**

```js
var qType = "INTEGER"
var clickCount=0
if(qType === "INTEGER"){
        let intAnswer = document.createElement("input");
        intAnswer.type = "text";
        intAnswer.id = "intA";
        let intSubmit = document.createElement("input");
        intSubmit.type = "button";
        intSubmit.onclick =test
        intSubmit.value = "Submit";
        qDiv.appendChild(intAnswer);
        qDiv.appendChild(intSubmit);
    }
    
    function test(){ 
    ++clickCount
    alert('click done:'+clickCount); };
```

```html
 <div id="qDiv"></div>
```